# If-else example in Javascript - Beginner

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in JavaScript from an example I'm learning from. I think the code is correct but I don't know how I would make it display itself. Can anyone help?

```
var num =2;
var bool = false;

if(num ==1 && bool==1) alert("TEST1 bool: "+ bool);
else

if(num ==2 && bool==1) alert("TEST2 bool: ")+ bool);
else

if(num ==2 && bool==0) alert("TEST3 bool: ")+ bool);
else

if(num ==3 && bool==0) alert("TEST4 bool: ")+ bool);
```

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Can you try explaining your problem, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: @CodeLღver `bool` is not a reserved word.

Comment: follow @sifriday advice, open web developer tools, switch to console, paste you code and run. Or put this code in file and include it with <script> to some html page and load it in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra parenthesis... Moreover you can remove else statements in this case.

```
var num =2; var bool = false;
if(num ==1 && bool==1) alert("TEST1 bool: "+ bool);
if(num ==2 && bool==1) alert("TEST2 bool: "+ bool);
if(num ==2 && bool==0) alert("TEST3 bool: "+ bool);
if(num ==3 && bool==0) alert("TEST4 bool: "+ bool);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the browser console, or with a tool like jsfiddle, or by saving it to an HTML file and opening that file in your browser.

You do also have a typo in your code - you need to remove some brackets. And if you are going to define `bool = false` then be aware that when you compare it to `1` and `0` this only works because JS is loosely typed. 1 is coerced to be equivalent to true and 0 is coerced to be equivalent to false.

```
var num =2;
var bool = false;

if(num ==1 && bool==1) alert("TEST1 bool: "+ bool);
else

if(num ==2 && bool==1) alert("TEST2 bool: "+ bool);
else

if(num ==2 && bool==0) alert("TEST3 bool: "+ bool);
else

if(num ==3 && bool==0) alert("TEST4 bool: "+ bool);
```

**JSFiddle Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/mx3eyhxf/

JSFiddle is nice for this kind of thing because you can load in libraries like jQuery really easily.

**Browser Console**

As @Evegeniy says in his comment above, to do this simply open your web developer tools, switch to console, paste your code and run.

**File**

Create an HTML file like:

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var num =2;
            var bool = false;

            if(num ==1 && bool==1) alert("TEST1 bool: "+ bool);
            else

            if(num ==2 && bool==1) alert("TEST2 bool: "+ bool);
            else

            if(num ==2 && bool==0) alert("TEST3 bool: "+ bool);
            else

            if(num ==3 && bool==0) alert("TEST4 bool: "+ bool);
        </script>
     </head>
     <body></body>
</html>
```

and open that in your browser.

Comment: This answer is attracting some controversy! It is currently -2 and +2. Any insight from the downvoters as to why, then I can improve it?

Answer (score 0):

var bool is of type boolean use bool for bool == 1 and !bool for bool==0 also there is one extra parenthesis in alert

```
 var num =2; var bool = false;

  if(num ==1 && bool) 
        alert("TEST1 bool: "+ bool); 
  else if(num ==2 && bool) 
       alert("TEST2 bool: "+ bool); 
 else if(num ==2 && !bool) 
      alert("TEST3 bool: "+ bool); 
 else if(num ==3 && !bool) 
     alert("TEST4 bool: "+ bool);
```